# MailChimp API 3.0 batch/bulk subscribe

Tags: php, python, mailchimp, restful-architecture, mailchimp-api-v3.0

For MailChimp API 2.0 there was a method 'batch-subscribe', to send in an array of email addresses to be added to a specific list in MailChimp.
How to implement this in the new Rest Architecture based MailChimp API 3.0?
See https://github.com/mailchimp/APIv3-examples/wiki/Overview
It says it would work with array of objects
But by the schema it only accepts an object
Schema https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Lists/Members/Collection.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you're linking to look like docs from the beta, but either way, they say that batch operations aren't yet implemented. FWIW, the real docs also list Batch Operations as a part of [the roadmap](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/article/3-roadmap), so I doubt they're done yet.

Comment: So I think I'll go with API 2.0 for now!! Thanks anyways

Answer (score 10):

MailChimp API v3.0 is now live! and they've also added a better *batch operations* feature which lets you make multiple operations in just one call. 
You can use below code with the help of this [php wrapper for MailChimp apiV3](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/tree/api-v3) for the batch operations.

```
    $data1 =array(
            'email_address' => 'testingmail1@gmail.com',
            'status' => 'subscribed',
            'merge_fields' => array('FNAME' => 'Testing', 'LNAME' => 'Mail1'));
    $data2 =
        array(
            'email_address' => 'testingmail2@example.com',
            'status' => 'subscribed',
            'merge_fields' => array('FNAME' => 'Testing', 'LNAME' => 'Mail2'));
    $attributes = array(
        'operations' => array(
            array(
                'path' => 'lists/' . $listID . '/members',
                'method' => 'POST',
                'body' => json_encode($data1)
            ),
            array(
                'path' => 'lists/' . $listID . '/members',
                'method' => 'POST',
                'body' => json_encode($data2)
            ),
        ));

    $response = $MailChimp->post('batches/', $attributes);
```

Comment: {"status_code":400,"operation_id":null,"response":"{\"type\":\"http:\/\/developer.mailchimp.com\/documentation\/mailchimp\/guides\/error-glossary\/\",\"title\":\"Invalid Resource\",\"status\":400,\"detail\":\"The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.\",\"instance\":\"\",\"errors\":[{\"field\":\"\",\"message\":\"Schema describes object, NULL found instead\"}]}"}]

Comment: This blog post from mailchimp should also help understand what you need to do https://devs.mailchimp.com/blog/batch-operations-and-put-in-api-v3-0/

Comment: Instead of "POST", use "PUT" and add the member id, which is `md5($email)` as a property of each data object.  I believe the lack of `id` property is what's causing the errror.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue at the Mailchimp end. You just need to use arrays and objects properly.

Good batch subscribe example you can find here https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/wp-users-to-mailchimp-list.html#batch_subscribe_php

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. It was an issue at the Mailchimp end. We reported it and they got it fixed in a day or so.