# How to subscribe many members at one request using MailChimp.Net - A Mail Chimp 3.0 Wrapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Here they published the https://github.com/brandonseydel/MailChimp.Net api 3.0, it is live now.  But they didn't say anything about how to use batch to upload many members in one request.

I have searched in stackoverflow and also google, they either implement using php or said it was not supported yet. such as from this topic ([MailChimp API 3.0 batch/bulk subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298612/mailchimp-api-3-0-batch-bulk-subscribe)), was from 2015.  As a year passed, just wonder anyone know how can I send multiple members (email addresses) to a list in one request using the .net api 3.0

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Take a look at issues on API GitHub repository.
In this one there is code that may help you:
https://github.com/brandonseydel/MailChimp.Net/issues/107

Comment: Thanks, that maybe a solution, I will try with that. And since you are working in this as well, I am wondering how much time does it take to subscribe 1000 members? It seems takes a long time, like 20 seconds. (While I am using .net API 2)

Comment: I still have not tested with a lot of subscribers. I suppose it is the same as in API V2.

Comment: Thanks anyway, but the function there for API3 is working right? I will try with that later. Right now I have changed to use API2, and struggling in the long time issue now. I will get back to you after I have tried API3 with the method you mentioned.

Comment: Yes it works. I'm currently working on batch subscribe.

Comment: I just tried with the method from you link, but each time when I run to var batch = mc.Batches.AddAsync(batchRequest).Result; it just go back to the view, and nothing happens. The members are not imported in mailchimp, do you know why?

Comment: You need to wait for the operation to finish. After that check the results.

Comment: It is never going to finish.. No idea why. And no idea when it can be done as well. As async, it just go back to my view. and not even continue running to next line.